# How to use defaultValue in the select tag in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, default-value

I have a functional component that contains a select tag with a few options. 
I want to set cars as the default value.
Initially, I simply added selected in the car's option but react gave me a warning saying I should be using defaultValue in the select tag instead. I was wondering how I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
function ChooseOptions(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Choose Options</h2>
      <label>
        New Only <input type="checkbox" />
      </label>

      <label
        htmlFor="selectType"
        style={{ display: "block" }}
        defaultValue="Cars"
      >
        Select Type
        <select id="selectType">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="cars">Cars</option>
          <option value="trucks">Trucks</option>
          <option value="convertibles">Convertibles</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

You will get the change value in 'onChange' props,

You can set value by passing 'value' props

```
  <select id="selectType" defaultValue="cars">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="cars">Cars</option>
            <option value="trucks">Trucks</option>
            <option value="convertibles">Convertibles</option>
        </select>
```